# How do I check a class in parse? - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, authentication, parse-platform

My program is set up so you log in, and you choose to upgrade. So you login and it saves your username and password into the "User" class of parse, then when you upgrade your account it stores all the information it had you input, ie. Phone number, etc. I also have it store your username, and this is in the "Upgrade" class. But when I log in, I want my program to check if the user upgraded their account. 
My current code:

```
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {

var username = self.usernameTextField.text
var pasword = self.passwordTextField.text

if (password.isEmpty) {
```

Here I have an UIAlert which is unimportant

```
}
else {
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password: password, block: {( user, error) ->Void in
if ((user) != nil) {
```

Here is the issue. Right here is the point where I wuold perform my segue if they are a regular user. But within this statement I want to put another statement to check if it is an upgraded account. I have tried this:

```
var upgradeUser:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Business")
```

I tried declaring that but now what do I put in my if statement? Essentially I need something like this:

```
if (upgradeUser has the current user's username) {
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginSegue2", sender: nil)
}
```

I tried using wherekeys and findobjectWithId, but none seem to work.I just need to login with user, then check the upgrade class if this user's username is found within that class. Any suggestions? Or proper ways to use what I have already tried?

Comment: What are the available properties on your Business class? A PFObject isn't the same thing as a PFUser and you're going to need to have something you can compare that's identical between them.

Comment: Sorry my 2 classes I need to compare are my User class and Upgrade class. In both I have the username, so if someones username was "John" it would appear in both classes. In the user class, the username is "John". BUt in my upgrade class, I believe I have the username "John" as an object. (Sorry if this didn't make any sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PFUser is a subclass of PFObject so you can use `setObject:forKey:` on your PFUser object and make it a bool ([How to set a bool](https://www.parse.com/questions/a-boolean-data-type)), i.e. `userIsUpgraded:true/false`

Comment: Im still a little fuzzy on this. I understand I need to make it Bool. But where do I put the code? Do I put it in my if statement, or do I put it before, like around where I created my variables? Then also, I need to check the upgrade class for my username and make sure it is equal to a username in the User class. How do I check for that?

Comment: I would set the bool when you first create the user, and set it to false. Then, when your user has upgraded his or her account you can set the flag to true. Why do you need to check if a username is equal to a user class?

Comment: I am have been trying to create a bool, but cant seem to get it to work. Do you have any other links to help me learn? Or do I need to set my PFUser.currentUser() as a bool false if they havent upgraded? And if so, how would I do  that?

Comment: @JCDOSAJ I think you will have to dive into the documentation and read up on it a bit more, as I haven't done this exact thing myself. I hope you figure it out!